# How to disable checkbox if textarea empty in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, attributes, angular6

I have textarea and checkbox in my Angular template.
Textarea can be with or without value, it depends of my api.
I want to add attribute disabled to my checkbox if textarea empty, and does not add if textarea has it

Something like:

```
<textarea name="descriptionText" formControlName="descriptionText">
</textarea>
<input type="checkbox" [disabled]="!descriptionText.length" />
```

Comment: do you have ngModel in textarea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ngModel to achieve this goal

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="text"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" [disabled]="!text || text.length <= 0" />
```

Adding `!text` check you can avoid to declare text var into your ts component.

Remember to import ngModel into your ts component like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```